# what are IFL IFD and IFA

Tags: vlan, juniper, interface

I came across terms like IFL IFD and IFA 's recently when studying some articles related to my project, I dont clearly understand what they are and the difference between them. I know they are related to interfaces within networking devices. I came across these terms when studying article on Juniper network's website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This juniper-nsp email](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/nsp/juniper/23778#23778) explains them pretty clearly...

> We try to avoid the terms "ifd" and "ifl" completely in our docs,
>   but these internal terms have slipped out in a few places. The
>   relationship is fairly simple: "ifd" is the physical interface
>   device, where "ifl" is the logical interface (aka unit). Logical
>   interfaces are arranged as children of a physical interface... As an example, [interfaces so-1/2/3] would be a physical interface and [interfaces so-1/2/3 unit 0] would be a logical unit. The organization hierarchy continues down with address families (iff) as [... family inet] and addresses (ifa) as [... address 10.1.2.3/24].

In summary:

- ifd: A Junos Physical Interface
- ifl: A [Junos Logical Interface](http://forums.juniper.net/t5/Junos/Juniper-logical-interface-concept/td-p/163660) (how individual vlans on a physical interface are distinguished)
- ifa: A Junos interface address

Comment: Another term that is used sometimes is IFF for interface family. For example `interface ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family inet`